# How to open activity/fragment when SensorEventListener is triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sensors

I am trying to work with SensorEventListener, when phone shake is detected, I want to open a fragment `GetInTouchMenuFragment` through activity GetInTouchActivity

`onCreate` method of Activity is not called at all. so fragment is not shown.

this is my `SensorEventListener` in `MainActivity`.

MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 // Getting the Sensor Manager instance
        sensorManager = this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager

        Objects.requireNonNull(sensorManager)!!
            .registerListener(sensorListener, sensorManager!!
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)

}

private val sensorListener: SensorEventListener = object : SensorEventListener {
    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {

        // Fetching x,y,z values
        val x = event.values[0]
        val y = event.values[1]
        val z = event.values[2]
        lastAcceleration = currentAcceleration

        // Getting current accelerations
        // with the help of fetched x,y,z values
        currentAcceleration = sqrt((x * x + y * y + z * z).toDouble()).toFloat()
        val delta: Float = currentAcceleration - lastAcceleration
        acceleration = acceleration * 0.9f + delta

        // Display a Toast message if
        // acceleration value is over 12
        if (acceleration > 12) {
            Log.d("GetInTouchActivity", "first")
            GetInTouchActivity.createIntent(this@MainActivity)
            Log.d("GetInTouchActivity", "second")
        }
    }
    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor, accuracy: Int) {}
}
```

GetInTouchActivity

```
class GetInTouchActivity : InjectionFragmentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.get_in_touch_activity)

        setAppBar(toolbar, showHomeAsUp = true, navIcon = AppBarNavIcon.BACK_ARROW_BLACK)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d("GetInTouchActivity", "onCreate") // NOT EXECUTED
            showFragment(GetInTouchMenuFragment.newInstance())
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        reporter.reportEvent(javaClass.simpleName.processScreenName(), "Back")

        finish()
    }

    companion object {
        fun createIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            Log.d("GetInTouchActivity", "createIntent") // EXECUTED
            return Intent(context, GetInTouchActivity::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest what I am doing wrong here please, why `onCreate` in `GetInTouchActivity` is not called

Thank you for your assistance
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is your `startActivity(..)` call? :) its necessary to start new `Activity`, creating an `Intent` is not sufficient

```
val createdIntent = GetInTouchActivity.createIntent(this@MainActivity)
startActivity(createdIntent)
```

Comment: you are right, I missed to add that, it was a copy paste error, my bad. thank you for this.